# Scheduled reminder wants a choice of auto renewal options but auto renewal is off - price set issue?

Tags: civimember, scheduled-reminders

We don't use auto renewal (Auto Renew Option set to NO for all membership types), but we do use price sets. I am trying to test automated reminders for membership expiration, but I am being prompted to choose from the auto renew options list, which is empty. This is CiviCRM 5.50.2 on Wordpress 6. I see that there have been issues around price sets and auto renew, but we don't want auto renew at all. Am I missing something simple - is there a way to populate the auto renew options with "No"? Thanks for any help you can provide!

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the membership type's [auto-renewal should be either optional or required](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/Civi/ActionSchedule/Mapping.php#L212) if you want to use the reminders for Membership.

Comment: Pradeep - presumably that is an accidental restriction from the way the form is coded?  There's no good reason not to be able to use scheduled reminders with non-autorenewing memberships is there?

Comment: I agree, @Aidan - in fact if auto-renewal is on it seems like you wouldn't need a reminder at all, rather an alert along the lines of "heads up your membership will be renewed, you don't need to do anything unless you want to cancel." I would want separate wording for optional and required at minimum, so they'd have to be separate reminders. I can try turning it on optional as a test though...

Comment: When I turn on optional renewal, I can successfully set up a reminder, and I have the choice to choose off, on, or both. So my issue is solved - thanks, Pradeep! I do think this limitation should be fixed though (even just a selectable n/a in the drop-down?), as I don't see why non-auto renewals can't be set up this way.

Comment: Logged as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3987